How do I write a mathematical equation for ARIMA (1,1,1) x (1,1,0) period 12
I would appreciate it if someone could assist me in writing the mathematical equation for the seasonal ARIMA (1,1,1) x (1,1,0) period 12. I'm a little confused with how to go about this. I would prefer an equation involving Yt, θ,  and Θ.
This is my Rstudio auto.arima coefficients values:
Series: Time_series_Data
ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,0)[12]
Coefficients:
ar1      ma1     sar1
0.6281  -0.9459  -0.3067
s.e.  0.1006   0.0565   0.0955
sigma^2 = 197.3:  log likelihood = -531.72
AIC=1071.44   AICc=1071.76   BIC=1082.94

Have you tried searching for similar questions? There are dozens of them on Cross Validated, and some have good answers. Yours will quite certainly be marked as a duplicate.

I couldn't find a formula that includes coefficients. I opened this topic because I am a little inexperienced in this subject.

All the formulas involve coefficients.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+equation.  Also, searching for ar1 ma1 sar1 returns many directly relevant posts.
